# Life in a Neptune atmosphere?

Tags: evolution, aliens, gas-giants

https://phys.org/news/2021-06-life-atmosphere-sub-neptune-planet.html This article suggests that if extremaphiles were transported by meteorite to a neptune-like planet they might be able to establish a thriving ecosystem in the atmosphere of the planet. How plausible is this really? For sake of argument let's assume the planet is in the habitable zone.

Comment: Well, one interesting thing about gas giants is that typically as you go deeper into the atmosphere it gets warmer (albeit with higher pressure) so you might not even have to worry about the habitable zone thing. I don't have any scientific data to back this up (hence not posting as an answer) but I'd shoot for putting the microbes at a depth where the pressure is similar to being submerged in water on Earth and the planet in a location where that's a viable temperature. Then you could have life behave similarly to how it does in our oceans, I'd expect.

Comment: The article makes the argument.

Comment: Both Space Exporation https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrobiology and Biology Stacks https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrobiology have astrobiology tags, if you don't get what you want here and want sciencey answers you might want to try one of these instead, or at least have a look to see if they have anything of interest...

Answer (score 1):

**Life would have to endure harsh conditions**

As the article states, a gas giant's atmosphere could indeed facilitate lifeforms, like extremophile bacteria to survive the conditions that exist in certain altitude bands. Unless all species have "extremophile" properties,  this "goldylock" band, supporting your ecosystem, could be narrow. All depends on 1) temperature gradient and 2) the atmosphere's density and 3) the overall density of life required to keep a complete ecosysyem running.

**No orbiting**

Unlike Niven's Ring World, which consists of giant trees orbiting a sun in space, anything that resides in the ideal band inside a gas giant's atmosphere cannot perform orbital movement because of friction caused by the atmosphere and the gravitational field of the planet. As a result, the natural direction of movement would be *toward* the planet's surface. That would count for any lifeform having a higher density than the local density in the atmosphere where the temperature is ok.

**Ability to fly**

Larger animals, that have a density that exceeds than the local density of the atmosphere would fall and die, unless able to actively fly, to gain height. They also need to fly, because the food will reside in the lower regions..

**A quasi-surface layer could form**

The base of the food chain will be lower lifeforms, like bacteria, algae and fungi. These will thrive on the carbon remains of larger lifeforms that fall toward the planet after death. They would therefore reside in the lower regions of the band. Food will be no issue there. Algae and fungi could even form a surface-like layer, on top of which plant life can emerge.